# ¿Cómo obtener el índice de una Lista con Criteria API JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

Necesito acceder a la primera componente de la lista Objeto2, usando una Query que obtiene un Object1 mediante Criteria API.

```
public class Object1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="column1")
    private Integer column1;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="object2")
    private List<Object2> object2;
}
```

He pensado algo similar a esto:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();


CriteriaQuery<Object1> query = cb.createQuery(Object1.class);
Root<Object1> object1 = query.from(Object1.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

Path<List<Object2>> path = object1.get("object2").get(0).get(....)      
predicates.add(cb.equal(placeIdPath, placeId));
```

Apreciaría muchísimo una respuesta.
Gracias!

Comment: La pregunta no deja claro el escenario: la lista de `Object2` no está ordenada, así que con *el primer objeto* no sé si quieres decir *el primero que se encuentre* (uno cualquiera) o si quieres alguno en particular. ¿Qué problema tienes con el código actual?

Comment: Perdona por la explicación. Quiero obtener el objeto que esté en la primera componente de la lista. Si lo quisiéramos obtener en una lista normal sería: lista.get(0). Mi problema es que como la Lista está dentro del Path, no puedo acceder de esta forma. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo lógico sería no buscar a través de Object1, sino directamente a través de Object2, filtrando por la FK que enlaza con Object1... Sería algo similar a:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object2> critQ = cb.createQuery(Object2.class);
Root<Object2> root = critQ.from(Object2.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
//dame los registros de object2 relacionados con el obj1 con id...
predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("object1_id", obj1Id));

critQ.where(predicates);

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(critQ);
query.setMaxResults(1);
return query.getResultList().get(0);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, creo que más o menos la solución está por ahí. Realmente, al final se obtiene de la query un Object1, pero quería acceder a la primera componente para compararlo con un valor.